# ggplot2 Dodge overlapping - preserve the width of each element

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hope it will be easy to understand. It's basically the same example as [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html).

[image]

Using

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs))) +
   geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))
```

But I'm getting `Error in position_dodge(preserve = "single") : 
  unused argument (preserve = "single")`/. ggplot2 version 2.2.1

So how to modify code

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs))) +
     geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

To not get this super wide bar like below but same as there.
[image]

Comment: I also have this error. A proper solution would be appreciated.

Comment: @ThirstforKnowledge didn't find anything yet. I'm actually thinking about building dummy data to fill empty values, but it's for shiny so i need to automate everything somehow, and make function read what exactly is missing.

Answer (score 4):

That argument was added to `position_dodge` in the development version [in january](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/commit/42d6e60ed0a0c9f5f60d212116346519b48fe9b5). It's not yet on CRAN.

A workaround would be to calculate the statistics outside ggplot2:

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(with(mtcars, table(cyl = factor(cyl), vs = factor(vs)))), 
       aes(factor(cyl), y = Freq, fill = factor(vs))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image: resulting plot]

This works because the zero count is included in the data passed to the geom.